# How to bold a RichTextBox through button click?

Tags: wpf, formatting, richtextbox, bold

The code I am currently using to bold the text currently is this:

```
rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```

but the drawback of this having to highlight the text first before the bold can be applied.

Is there a way to make the next typed text in the RichTextBox bold without having to highlight and select text?

Comment: have u checked the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rtb.CaretPosition.Parent is TextElement)
{
  (rtb.CaretPosition.Parent as TextElement).FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
}
```